# Adjusting 2 dimensional array's?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, ascii

I made a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
    char Grid[][] = {
    {'#','#','#'}
    {'#','#','#'}
    {'#','#','#'}
    }
```

and displayed it with this:

```
        for (int row = 0; row < Grid.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < Grid[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(Grid[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I want to be able to simple adjust the elements in the array, like adding and removing elements. Since basic java (for some reason) doesn't seem to have any predefined functions to do this, i tried using the ArrayUtils class from common langs. I found a couple methods in the docs including "Add", "insert", and "remove" and tried something like this:

```
        ArrayUtils.insert(Scene, Grid, 2); //(With "Scene" being the class name)
```

But as expected, it didn't work.

On another website, i read something about cloning the array, but i don't think this is the solution to my problem since i want to be able to move around an ASCII character, and i don't want to create a new array each time i move it.

EDIT: To be clear, i want to be able to either CHANGE the index value's or quickly remove then and place another on the exact spot.

Comment: Arrays are not resizable. Try using lists instead.

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do with your array? You can just chance an element of it, but you can't make them longer or shorter after you've allocated them. You say you want to adjust the array, but you're not very clear what exact adjustments that you want to make, or why ArrayUtils.insert isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arrays are basic types and are not used to add elements, for these operations ArrayList and depending if there is many inserts and deletes at any places LinkedList may be more convenient. ArrayUtils.insert should return a new array instance doing a copy of initial array.

Answer (score 0):

Once created an array in java is with fixed length so in your case after you have used the Array Inicializer you end up with an **array with length 3**, having elements of type **char array** where each of them is with fixed length of 3 as well. To replace a given value all you need is to assign the new value to the proper indexes like :

```
Grid[i][j] = 'new character value';
```

As I've already said since the size is fixed you can not add new values to it, unless u copy the entire array in a new array of size (length +1) and place the new value on the desired position. Simple code demonstrating that:

```
private static void add(char[][] grid, int row, int column, char value) {
    if (row < 0 || row > grid.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("No such row with index " + row + " inside the matrix."); // you are trying to insert an element out of the array's bounds.
    }
    if (column < 0 || column > grid[row].length) {
        /*
         * An array in Java is with fixed length so you should keep the index inside the size!
         */
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Index " + column + " does not exists in the extended array!"); // you are trying to insert an element out of the array's bounds.
    }

    boolean flag = false; //indicates that the new element has been inserted.
    char[] temp = new char[grid[row].length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (i == column) {
            temp[i] = value;
            flag = true;
        } else {
            temp[i] = grid[row][i - (flag ? 1 : 0)];
        }
    }

    grid[row] = temp; //assign the new value of the whole row to it's placeholder.
}
```

To remove an element from the array you would have to make a new array with size[length - 1], skip the element you would like to remove and add all the others. Assign the new one to the index in the matrix then. Simple code:

```
private static void remove(char[][] grid, int row, int column) {
    if (row < 0 || row > grid.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("No such row with index " + row + " inside the matrix."); // you are trying to insert an element out of the array's bounds.
    }
    if (column < 0 || column > grid[row].length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("No such column with index " + column + " at row " + row + " inside the matrix."); // you are trying to insert an element out of the array's bounds.
    }

    boolean flag = false; //indicates that the element has been removed.
    char[] temp = new char[grid[row].length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (i == column) {
            flag = true;
        }
        temp[i] = grid[row][i + (flag ? 1 : 0)];
    }

    grid[row] = temp; //assign the new value of the whole row to it's placeholder.
}
```

If I define a method called `print(char[][] grid)` and put the code you use for printing then i'm able to do these tests:

```
add(Grid, 2, 3, '$'); //Add an element.
print(Grid);
System.out.println();
remove(Grid, 2, 0); // Remove an element.
print(Grid);
System.out.println();
Grid[0][0] = '%'; // Change an element's value.
print(Grid);
```

And the output is as follows:

```
###
###
###$

###
###
##$

%##
###
##$
```